# HornetQ message redelivery with useExponentialBackOff

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging, hornetq

In ActiveMQ it is possible to set useExponentialBackOff in redelivery policy which would exponentially increase the delay every time the message consumption fails. How to achieve that in HornetQ?

Is it possible to define own redelivery policy as a java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:

```
<address-settings>
      <address-setting match="jms.queue.example">
         <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.deadletter</dead-letter-address>
         <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
         <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>
         <redelivery-delay-multiplier>2.0</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
      </address-setting>
</address-settings>
```

- redelivery-delay-multiplier: This allows you to implement an
  exponential backoff between redelivery attempts.
- max-delivery-attempts: Messages will forward to deadletter address (If it is specified),
  after max-delivery-attempts unsuccessful attempts.
- redelivery-delay: HornetQ will wait this delay before redelivering
  the messages

Comment: 2013-04-01 18:36:50,691 main ERROR org.hornetq.utils.XMLUtil  - Invalid configuration
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'redelivery-delay-multiplier'. One of '{"urn:hornetq":expiry-address, "urn:hornetq":max-size-bytes, "urn:hornetq":page-size-bytes, "urn:hornetq":page-max-cache-size, "urn:hornetq":address-full-policy, "urn:hornetq":message-counter-history-day-limit, "urn:hornetq":last-value-queue, "urn:hornetq":redistribution-delay, "urn:hornetq":send-to-dla-on-no-route}' is expected.

Comment: 2.2.21.Final. 2.3.0-CR1 does not sound like a final version.

Comment: I think it's a stable version. And recently, HornetQ-2.3.0.CR2 is released.

Comment: I'm not sure what CR does exactly stands for here, but most likely it's a "candidate for release"

Comment: 2.3.0.Final is dated 2013-04-24 - just under a month after @MojFar's answer!

Comment: As a tangentially related anecdote, when JBoss AS 7.0.0.Final shipped, it had Hibernate 4.0.0.Beta1 as its JPA provider. So using pre-release components as part of your product isn't entirely without precedent even in enterprise software ...